# why am I not able to receive data inputs from my USB joystick in labview?

Tags: labview, joystick

The following Labview code:

[image]

does not receive any data from my [USB Saitek X52 joystick](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LQ4HTS).  I am not able to figure out why.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice, move the 'Init Joystick' out the while loop, is there an error returned?
What input method have you used, does the read data return an error?

Comment: you were right about moving the init joystick outside the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't currently have a high enough reputation to comment on your original post, I'm having to ask for clarification here:

1) Attaching your LabView code as a VI snippet will allow others to properly see and edit your code.  From the block diagram select the menu "Edit" --> "Create VI snippet from selection"

2) Does this joystick show up in the National Instruments Measurement & Automation Explorer (MAX) program?  If not, you probably need to solve that problem first.